# geopandas self intersection grouping

Tags: python, geopandas

I am used to R, and am switching to python for some geo transformations.
For one task, I need to group polygons in a geopandas dataframe by intersection.

However, I can only find geopandas arguments that can do this between two dataframes.
For example, these two polygons in the dataframe:

[image]

should get the same group id.

I hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not interested in strictly pair-wise relation, you can use `libpysal` to get *group* labels.

Starting from dummy data:

```py
import geopandas as gpd

geom = gpd.points_from_xy([0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7], [0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 7]).buffer(1.2)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=geom)
```

[image: input data]

You can create fuzzy contiguity weights matrix based on intersection and get labels of connected components:

```py
W = libpysal.weights.fuzzy_contiguity(gdf)
W.component_labels
```

which returns an array:

```
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int32)
```

Plotted:

```py
gdf.plot(W.component_labels, alpha=.5, categorical=True)
```

[image: final]

Comment: great! thats what i was looking for. thanks!